# Flashloan error `reverted with reason string 'SafeERC20: low-level call failed'`

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, flash-loans, aave

I'm attempting to execute a flashloan on a forked mainnet within hardhat and am getting `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'SafeERC20: low-level call failed'`. I expected this to be reverted (since I do nothing with the funds) by Aave, but not for the reason stated above.

contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import "@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPool.sol";


contract Liquidator is FlashLoanReceiverBase {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider) FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider) public {}
    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    )
        external
        override
        returns (bool)
    {

        //
        // This contract now has the funds requested.
        // Your logic goes here.
        //

        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
        // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
        // these amounts.

        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function flashloan_test() public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        console.log(receiverAddress);
        address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
        assets[0] = address(0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F); // DAI

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        amounts[0] = 1 ether;

        // 0 = no debt, 1 = stable, 2 = variable
        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](1);
        modes[0] = 0;

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
    }
}
```

flashloan-test.js

```
const Liquidator = await ethers.getContractFactory("Liquidator");
    const liquidator = await Liquidator.deploy("0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5");
    await liquidator.deployed();

    expect(await liquidator.flashloan_test()).to.equal("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: have you managed to understand what's happening there? I do experience this issue as well but it's not very deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have tokens of the target assets in the smart contract in order to pay for the premiums

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use a lesser amount of ETH that will take a loan. For example try to use =>

amounts[0] = 0.01 ether;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).